# How to get the SecurityContext from within a DataFetcher (WebFlux + DGS GraphQL)

Tags: spring-security, netflix-dgs, spring-graphql

I am wondering if it is possible to obtain the `Authentication` from within the `onField` function contained in a `SchemaDirectiveWiring`.

I've looked into using the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` and `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` and `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().block().getAuthentication()`, but both return null (which does make sense since its being called from within an asynchronous thread).

I therefore looked into using the `[ReactiveDgsContext][1]` which looks promising as when debugging the code, I can see within the reactorContext that there is a SecurityContext key/value, but I don't know how to access it/retrieve it properly.

Currently, my code looks as follows:

```
DataFetcher<?> authDataFetcher = DataFetcherFactories
                .wrapDataFetcher(originalFetcher, ((dataFetchingEnvironment, value) -> {
                    ReactiveDgsContext context = ReactiveDgsContext.from(dataFetchingEnvironment);
                    if(context != null){
                        ContextView reactiveContext = context.getReactorContext();
...
                    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to figure out a way of getting the Authentication out of the ReactiveDgsContext object, but as a workaround, I created a custom context.

```
public record CustomContext(ServerRequest webExchange, SecurityContext securityContext) {
}
```

And then registered it as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class DgsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DgsReactiveCustomContextBuilderWithRequest<CustomContext> dgsReactiveCustomContextBuilder() {
        return (map, httpHeaders, serverRequest) -> ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(securityContext -> new CustomContext(serverRequest, securityContext))
                .defaultIfEmpty(new CustomContext(serverRequest, null));
    }

}
```

Then you can access it as follows:

```
DataFetcher<?> authDataFetcher = DataFetcherFactories
                .wrapDataFetcher(originalFetcher, ((dataFetchingEnvironment, value) -> {
                    ReactiveDgsContext context = ReactiveDgsContext.from(dataFetchingEnvironment);
                    if (context != null) {
                        CustomContext customContext = (CustomContext) context.getCustomContext();
                        if (customContext != null) {
                            Authentication authentication = customContext.securityContext().getAuthentication();
                            ....
                        }
                    }
```

Alternatively, you can also get the JWT token from the headers and check it again, but given this has already been done, I didn't want to do it again (using Firebase so would be multiple calls to the oauth server).

Credit to ChatGPT for the help on this one - if anyone has a better way to do this (maybe using ReactiveDgsContext I would be interested in seeing it!)