Unable to retrieve Authentication information using ReactiveSecurityContextHolder
In my spring boot application, I am using spring-security and I have implemented WebFilter to set the Authentication in ReactiveSecurityContextHolder. However when I try to retrieve it back, the Authentication object is coming as null.
Here is the code example snippet to reproduce the issue I am facing.
The Spring-boot Application starter class as below:
@EnableWebFlux
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf(csrfSpec -> csrfSpec.disable())
                .authorizeExchange(auth -> auth.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")
                        .authenticated())
                .httpBasic(httpBasicSpec -> httpBasicSpec.disable())
                .addFilterBefore(customWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .build();
    }
    public WebFilter customWebFilter() {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            Authentication authenticatedToken =
                    new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken("User_PreAuthenticated", "");
            authenticatedToken.setAuthenticated(true);
            return chain.filter(exchange)
                    .contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authenticatedToken));
        };
    }
}

Here is the code from which I am trying to retrieve the Authentication from ReactiveSecurityContextHolder, However the authentication object is coming null.
// This authentication object is coming null.
Authentication authentication = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
.map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
.toFuture().getNow(null); 
        

I have referred to multiple StackOverflow questions and documentation around this, however I am unable to fix this specific issue. Am I missing anything?
UPDATE 1:
Thanks @kerbermeister for explaining in details about reactive chain and how it works, As requested, Here is the further explanation on why do I need this current user authentication principal outside of reactive chain.
I am using graphql-java with this spring-boot application and I need the current user details inside the graphql datafetcher during the processing of any gql query.
When I was on Spring MVC, I was able to use SecurityContext (ThreadLocal) to get the authenticated principal in the graphql datafetcher. However, I am not able to do the similar thing with Spring Webflux/Reactive.
Here is the code snipped of the Graphql query wirinig and datafetcher.
public List<TypeRuntimeWiring.Builder> buildWiring() {
        return Arrays.asList(newTypeWiring("Query").dataFetcher("getUserName",
                getCurrentUser()));
    }

    private DataFetcher getCurrentUser() {
        return dataFetchingEnvironment -> {
            String currentUser = "NOT_AVAILABLE";
            Authentication authentication = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                    .toFuture().getNow(null);
            // Here the Authentication value is coming null
            if (authentication != null) {
                Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
                if (principal != null && principal instanceof User) {
                    currentUser = ((User) principal).getUsername();
                }
            }
            return currentUser;
        };
    }

If it helps, I can also provide github link to an demo app for this.

You added it before the authentication filter, hence authentication is still null as it hasn't taken place yet. You would need to move it to after the execution of the authentication filter.

Thanks @M.Deinum for taking time to answer,  I have tried that by changing the addFilterBefore to addFilterAfter and also addFilterAt too and the result is still same., the authentication still remains null.

which graphql framework are you using? netflix dgs? spring-graphql? another one?

As you're in reactive paradigm, you should stay reactive all the way.
In reactive application the Authentication is stored in the subscriber context, not in ThreadLocal as it typically implemented in Spring MVC (not reactive application).
So, when you're attempting to retrieve Authentication this way:
// This authentication object is coming null.
Authentication authentication = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
.map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
.toFuture().getNow(null); 

You're getting null because Authentication is bounded to the subscriber context.
You could noticed that ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext() returns Mono, so you should call it within your reactive chain without breaking it with blocking calls or other subscribe() methods
For example:
@GetMapping
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> endpoint() {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(securityContext -> securityContext.getAuthentication())
            .map(authentication -> authentication.getName())
            .map(userName -> ResponseEntity.ok(userName));
}


Thanks @kerbermeister for explaining it in details. I understand now that with reactive paradigm we do not get the security context outside of reactive chain. This means as I am trying to grab it using toFuture, it is coming null.
Now my actual requirement is to grab the Authentication Principal so I can use it application wide, like the graphql data fetchers. I was able to do it in Spring MVC using SecurityContextHolder.
Do you have any suggestions or workaround for this one?

@AmitChudasama could you give some examples of code and cases where you would like to retrieve Authentication?

Thanks @kerbermeister, I have updated the original question to include more details about graphql-java .

@AmitChudasama I'm not familiar with GraphQL in depth, but I think this thread may help you https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/issues/437 and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76293105/how-to-get-the-securitycontext-from-within-a-datafetcher-webflux-dgs-graphql
